# Finding an exact position of a smaller list inside a list (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, find, nested-lists

So i Have a list which is something like this:

```
list=[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.2, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 10.2, 10.0, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.1, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.2, 10.5, 10.9, 10.5, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.4, 10.7, 10.3, 10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.1, 9.9, 9.9, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.7, 9.8, 9.8, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.6, 9.7]
```

And then i also has a sublist which looks something like this:

`sublist=[9.9, 9.9, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8]`

now what I need to do with this smaller list, is that I have to find where this is located in the main list.
So in this case the result should be something like this: index=119 (I might be off with +/-1)

I've been trying to do this all day... And didnt find anything on the web...
I have a few ideas:

1) I find the first item of the sublist on the list....which in this case would be 4, so i check the next number which is also correct then the next which will be wrong and it would send it to find another 9.9 in the remaining list[4:] and do the same loop again...until an exact match is found

2) Then another idea is to somehow use strings
str(list)[1:-1].find(str(sublist)[1:-1]), which in this case would give the answer of 687...

Problem with these ideas is that they seem to be long and sloppy and also I haven't been able to make these ideas work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
l = [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.2, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 10.2, 10.0, 9.9, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.1, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.3, 10.2, 10.5, 10.9, 10.5, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.4, 10.7, 10.3, 10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.0, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 10.1, 9.9, 9.9, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.7, 9.8, 9.8, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.6, 9.7]
subl = [9.9, 9.9, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8]
for i in xrange(len(l)-len(subl)):
  if l[i:i+len(subl)] == subl:
    print 'found at pos', i
    break
else:
  print 'not found'
```

This prints `found at pos 118`.

P.S. I've renamed the variables so that `list` doesn't shadow the built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

```
ind = l.index(subl[0])
for i in xrange(l.count(subl[0])-1):
    if l[ind:ind+len(subl)] == subl:
        print (ind)
        break;
    ind = l.index(subl[0],ind+1)
```

This is an efficient way which will only compare when it knows at least the first value of `subl` is present.

Answer (score 1):

Your second idea can give a false positive: if the sublist were a single value, say 1, and the full list had only the value 11, it would find a match.  If you added leading and trailing separators into your string, this could be avoided.

Your first idea is halfway to the optimal solution; there is an algorithm (whose name escapes me at the moment) for determining how much of the substring you can "reuse", so that you never have to backtrack in the full string.  For example, suppose your current candidate failed because you found a 9.9 where you expected a 9.8; you don't need to revisit that element, because it matches the first element of the substring.  Those can be pre-computed, so you end up just walking down the full list in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = next(i for i in range(len(lst)-len(sublst)) if lst[i:i+len(sublist)] == sublst)
# 118
```